# What actually causes the map to change?

Tags: gigantic

In *Gigantic*, once a certain point is reached during the match, the giants clash, and the entire map is changed. It may have been mentioned in the tutorial, but I likely glossed right over it, but what actually causes this clash?

Is it when one giant has two wounds? Is it a certain time in the match? I can't seem recall anything from the tutorial, and I never notice any specific triggers when it actually happens during the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I found it!

There are two ways to trigger a Clash, according to the [game's website.](http://www.arcgames.com/en/games/Gigantic/news/detail/10463163/)

> - **Five (5) total rampages have been triggered between the Guardians**. Whether one team gets all five or both teams have a cumulative total of five (regardless of whether either scores a Wound), the game progresses to the Clash.
> - When either Guardian has only one Wound left. Even if it only takes two rampages, the game will immediately proceed to the Clash if a team manages to score two Wounds on the enemy Guardian.

Additionally, there is a progress bar visible on the HUD that indicates how near you are to a Clash.

[image: Image depicting how near you are to a Clash]

> Each diamond represents a rampage: green indicates a rampage for your Guardian, and red represents an enemy rampage. Watch your HUD for the transition to the Clash and follow your Guardians to the new Clash location.